# Get filesize of no-quota files in drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a way to get the filesize of files which take up no space (pre 2021) in the google drive api, such gsheets, gdocx files?
I have tried using `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/myfileid123` but only get  `"quotaBytesUsed": "0"`. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve your goal, for example, how about the following flow?

1. Copy the Spreadsheet with `"quotaBytesUsed": "0"` using the method of "Files: copy" of Drive API as a temporal file and retrieve the file ID of copied Spreadsheet.

   - By this, the copied Spreadsheet has the file size.
2. Retrieve the value of `quotaBytesUsed` of the copied Spreadsheet using the method of "Files: get" of Drive API.

   - By this, you can retrieve the value of `quotaBytesUsed` of the copied Spreadsheet.
3. Delete the copied Spreadsheet (temporal file) using the method of "Files: delete" of Drive API.

#### References:

- [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy)
- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
- [Files: delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete)

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.  - * Does "Files: copy-ing" the file require many resources?, Is a real copy created? I have a lot of files for which I want to retrieve the filesize